# Paytabs sdk integration issue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, paytabs

I am integrating the Paytabs sdk in swift.I got the error mentioned below. I have read all the posts related to paytabs in stackoverflow but nothing helped me.I am running it on real device and I have also removed the duplicate pod files like reachibility and IQKeyboardManager.After doing all this stuff its is not working. Kindly suggest me how i can resolve this error.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ActionSheetStringPicker", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in paytabs-iOS(PTFWCreditCardDetailsViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. There is mistake in Paytabs developer portal.They forgot to mention the pod file  'ActionSheetPicker-3.0'. Kindly add the pod file.